# Passing Variables in URL - PHP

Tags: php

Assume that I have a URL like this

```
http://subdomain.domain.com/folder1/abc?cat1=PTO2Cat2=HITOFF&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsearch-adv.htm&TEXT1=Value
```

In this URL, TEXT1 at the end keeps changing for various pages. The Value will not change though. So it will be something like

For Page 1

```
http://subdomain.domain.com/folder1/abc?cat1=PTO2Cat2=HITOFF&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsearch-adv.htm&TEXT1=Value
```

For Page 2

```
http://subdomain.domain.com/folder1/abc?cat1=PTO2Cat2=HITOFF&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsearch-adv.htm&TEXT2=Value
```

For Page n

```
http://subdomain.domain.com/folder1/abc?cat1=PTO2Cat2=HITOFF&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsearch-adv.htm&TEXTn=Value
```

How can I parametrize it? I tried something like this

```
for ($i=1;$i<=n;$i++)
{
$url = sprintf('http://subdomain.domain.com/folder1/abc?cat1=PTO2Cat2=HITOFF&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsearch-adv.htm&TEXT%d=Value',$i)
echo $url;
}
```

but it failed saying Sprintf too few arguments. Any suggestion, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have more than one % sign in that url, sprintf parses it and tries to assign arguments to every %'something' it finds, you should escape the url encoded values.

You might want to check: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

Comment: I added an answer to show simple way to escape the encoded values of the URL.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) because the more than one (additional)`%` is creating problem .

```
$url=urldecode('http://subdomain.domain.com/folder1/abc?cat1=PTO2Cat2=HITOFF&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsearch-adv.htm&TEXT%d=Value');
$url = sprintf($url,$i);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'http://subdomain.domain.com/folder1/abc?cat1=PTO2Cat2=HITOFF&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsearch-adv.htm&TEXT'.$i.'=Value';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the normal string also right, instead of using sprintf

```
 for ($i=1 ; $i < = n ; $i++ )
  {
    $url = "http://subdomain.domain.com/folder1/abc?cat1=PTO2Cat2=HITOFF&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsearch-adv.htm&TEXT".$i."=Value";
    echo $url;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got like this issue with using `file_get_contents` that get url query for [solr](/questions/tagged/solr) search engine. I just solved it by escaping the `%` percent sign in the url encoded string by adding an extra `%` before every `%` in the string as follows:

```
$str = "%s?q=WebSite:%s&sort=Date%%20desc&version=2.2&start=%s&rows=%s&indent=on&wt=json";
        return sprintf($str, $this->url, $this->website, $this->start, $rows);
```

Notice the double % after the `Date` in the string.